# Rendering Exceptions polluting phpunit console

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am using Laravel 8. I catch a custom exception in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` to render it like this:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
    });

    $this->renderable(function (MyCustomNotFoundException $exception) {
        return response()->json(['error' => $exception->getMessage()], 404);
    });
}
```

Now my controller endpoint looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param string $sku
 * @return JsonResponse
 * @throws \App\Exceptions\MyCustomNotFoundException
 */
public function includedPrograms(string $sku): JsonResponse
{
    $permanentSkus =  $this->includedPrograms->getFrom($sku);

    return response()->json(['included-programs' => $permanentSkus]);
}
```

And `$this->includedPrograms()` may throw my custom exception.

I also created a feature test for this endpoint:

```
public function testMyCustomItemCanNotBeFound()
{
    $response = $this->get('/api/v1/my-editions/123-322/included-programs');

    $response->assertStatus(404);
}
```

Now the test passes. However, on the terminal I see the exception including the full stacktrace. Is that on purpose? How can I hide it?

```
PHPUnit 9.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

[2021-05-19 14:00:06] testing.ERROR: Could not find HealyEdition with given SKU {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (App\\Exceptions\\MyCustomNotFoundException(code: 0): Could not find HealyEdition with given SKU at /var/www/html/app/Services/HealyEdition/IncludedProgram.php:15)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/Api/HealyEditionController.php(32): App\\Services\\HealyEdition\\IncludedProgram->getFrom()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\HealyEditionController->includedPrograms()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(254): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(695): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(103): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(55): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(44): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(697): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(672): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(60): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle()
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(52): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php(508): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php(292): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Testing\\TestCase->call()
#43 /var/www/html/tests/Feature/Api/HealyEditionControllerTest.php(22): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Testing\\TestCase->get()
#44 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(1526): Tests\\Feature\\Api\\HealyEditionControllerTest->testHealyEditionCanNotBeFound()
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(1132): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase->runTest()
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(722): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase->runBare()
#47 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(884): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestResult->run()
#48 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(677): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase->run()
#49 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(677): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestSuite->run()
#50 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(677): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestSuite->run()
#51 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(667): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestSuite->run()
#52 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(143): PHPUnit\\TextUI\\TestRunner->run()
#53 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(96): PHPUnit\\TextUI\\Command->run()
#54 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(61): PHPUnit\\TextUI\\Command::main()
#55 {main}
"} 
[2021-05-19 14:00:06] testing.ERROR: Could not find HealyEdition with given SKU {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (App\\Exceptions\\MyCustomNotFoundException(code: 0): Could not find HealyEdition with given SKU at /var/www/html/app/Services/HealyEdition/IncludedProgram.php:15)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/Api/HealyEditionController.php(32): App\\Services\\HealyEdition\\IncludedProgram->getFrom()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\HealyEditionController->includedPrograms()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(254): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(695): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(103): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(55): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter()
#12 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle()
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(44): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle()
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(697): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(672): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(636): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute()
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch()
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}()
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/InjectDebugbar.php(60): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Barryvdh\\Debugbar\\Middleware\\InjectDebugbar->handle()
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#28 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle()
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings->handle()
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#31 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#32 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#33 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle()
#34 /var/www/html/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(52): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#35 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle()
#36 /var/www/html/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#37 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle()
#38 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}()
#39 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then()
#40 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#41 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php(508): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle()
#42 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php(292): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Testing\\TestCase->call()
#43 /var/www/html/tests/Feature/Api/HealyEditionControllerTest.php(22): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Testing\\TestCase->get()
#44 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(1526): Tests\\Feature\\Api\\HealyEditionControllerTest->testHealyEditionCanNotBeFound()
#45 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(1132): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase->runTest()
#46 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(722): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase->runBare()
#47 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(884): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestResult->run()
#48 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(677): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestCase->run()
#49 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(677): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestSuite->run()
#50 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(677): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestSuite->run()
#51 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(667): PHPUnit\\Framework\\TestSuite->run()
#52 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(143): PHPUnit\\TextUI\\TestRunner->run()
#53 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(96): PHPUnit\\TextUI\\Command->run()
#54 /var/www/html/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit(61): PHPUnit\\TextUI\\Command::main()
#55 {main}
"} 
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.361, Memory: 36.50 MB

OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
```